# Using .mbtiles file from maptiler via mapproxy

Tags: python, wms, mbtiles, mapproxy, maptiler

How do I serve a local WMS using [mapproxy](https://mapproxy.org)?

As long as I stick to online-services (and a local cache) all works fine.

Now I've downloaded myself a complete set of OSM tiles in `.mbtiles` format from [maptiler](https://data.maptiler.com/downloads/planet/) which I would like to serve as a local wms using [mapproxy](https://mapproxy.org).

However as soon as I point the cache to the downloaded .mbtiles file, the map is empty and the server prints some warnings like the following:
 `mapproxy.image.tile - WARNING - unable to load tile <mapproxy.image.ImageSource object at 0x0000019C496D2D40>, removing it (reason was: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000019C496F58F0>)`

Anybody has an idea what I'm doing wrong here?
(as I said, using a .mbtiles cache created by mapproxy from an online-source works just fine...)

... I know that there's a couple of questions with similar problems starting some ~10 years ago (like [Serving MBTiles file via MapProxy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17100/195838)) but none of them provides any real help and no proper answer given so far.

(also if anyhow possible I'd very much like to use the .mbtiles file as-is!)

A minimal version of the `.yaml` config-file I'm using at the moment looks like this:

```
services:
  demo:
  wmts:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.

layers:
  - name: osm_local
    title: osm_local
    sources: [osm_local_cache]

osm_local_cache:
  sources: []
    grids: [webmercator]
      cache:
        type: mbtiles
        filename: D:\python_modules\osm_cache\osmcache.mbtiles

grids:
    webmercator:
        base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
```